# Convert all values in html file to MS-Word using PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have the HTML and PHP code as below. I have code one file `html2word.php`:

```
<form method="post" action="htmltortf.php">    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Convert html to doc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Choose the answer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio"  name="004" value="1" <?=($_POST['004']=='1' ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?>/>1</td>
            <td><input type="radio"  name="004" value="2" <?=($_POST['004']=='2' ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?>/>2</td>
            <td><input type="radio"  name="004" value="3" <?=($_POST['004']=='3' ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?>/>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=html2doc.doc");
        }
     ?>    
</form>
```

**What I need:**

When the user checked on radio box it is also display  the radio box is checked when I convert it to MS-Word.

**The problem:**

When I converted it to word document, it will display the radio box that I checked but it shows me the error message:

`Notice: Undefined index: 004 in C:\wamp\www\html to docv2\htmltortf.php on line 51`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks on submit button, form data sends to server. It stores in $_POST array, so when u display this page, u must check for any data receiver earlier or not.
Try something like that (replace radio buttons html with this code) :

```
<td><input type="radio"  name="004" value="1" <?=((isset($_POST['004']) && $_POST['004']=='1') ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?>/>1</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="004" value="2" <?=((isset($_POST['004']) && $_POST['004']=='2') ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?>/>2</td>
<td><input type="radio"  name="004" value="3" <?=((isset($_POST['004']) && $_POST['004']=='3') ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?>/>3</td>
```

Check full solution:
http://codepad.org/QThcTGdO

Comment: Many thanks, but it displays error message `Notice: Undefined index: 004 in C:\wamp\www\html to docv2\htmltortf.php on line 75`.When I convert it to word document it works.

Comment: this notice isn't critical error. this cozed coz i dont check if `isset($_POST['004'])`. If u'll show me your 75 line I'll say u with more exactly.

Comment: This is code on line 75 `<td><input type="radio"  name="004" value="1" <?=($_POST['004']=='1' ? 'checked="checked"' : '')?>/>1</td>`. Thanks,

Comment: I use this one it works but when I check on the one radio box and I convert it to Ms word, it will show all radio box are checked.How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: dude, if u just copy that code to all radiobuttons... so i guess u dont understand how it works.

Comment: i changed answer, check this one.